# Is there a touch method for UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, touch-event

I'd like to do an action if someone touches a predeclared `UILabel`, something like:

```
if (label is touched) {
    my actions;
}
```

Is there a method/way to do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use a gesture recognizer:

```
- (void)someSetupMethod {
    // ...
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = \
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapLabelWithGesture:)];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];
}

- (void)didTapLabelWithGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If I have multiple label's, Then how to recognise which label is tapped ???

Answer (score 12):

By default, `UILabel` isn't configured to accept touch input. However, if you use a `UIButton` instead and set it to have a custom appearance, you can make it look like a (single-line) label and have it respond to touch events.

Comment: This was really easy to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass it and override the touch methods. You probably want to override `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

Or just use a UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure userinteractionenabled is set to YES and then you can override the `touchesBegan:withEvent:`

Answer (score 0):

Just Add A category for UILabel Class and add your method to it.